# Несколько apk для одного приложения

Tags: android, unity3d, google-play

Доброго времени суток. Имеется игра под *Android* (создана в *Unity3D*). Для уменьшения размера я убрал поддержку *x86* процессоров и оставил только *ARMv7*, т.к *ARMv7* значительно подавляющее большинство. Недавно узнал, что у *Google Play* есть поддержка нескольких апк для одного приложения. Хочу сделать два апк: один только с поддержкой *ARMv7*, другой - только с x86, чтобы маркет раздавал соответствующий апк для девайса пользователя.
В консоли разработчика явно не понятно как это делается. Может кто-то имел с подобным дело, подскажите пожалуйста, как это осуществить? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно переключиться в Advanced mode в консоли, затем заливать и активировать apk по одному. Как я понимаю, единственное, что они на самом деле сделали, это они позволили быть активными нескольким apk одновременно. Дальше просто отрабатывает фильтр, который находит самый "свежий" apk для конкретного устройства. Соответственно, у них должны быть разные номера версий, причем в нужном порядке, подробнее здесь: https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html#Rules

> Before you can publish your application (whether publishing one or multiple APKs), you must "activate" your APK(s) from the APK files tab. When you activate an APK, it moves into the list of Active APKs. This list allows you to preview which APK(s) you're about to publish.
>
> If there are no errors, any "active" APK will be published to Google Play when you click the Publish button (if the application is unpublished) or when you click the Save button (if the application is already published).

Comment: Да, видел эту страницу, жаль на русском языке нет. Получается надо просто залить один за одним два apk с разными `code version` и они оба будут доступны под соответственно наиболее подходящее устройство?

Comment: Я цитату об этом выше добавил.